# If $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices such that $A\geq B$. Then can we say $A^{-1} \leq B^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A \geq 0$ and $B\geq 0$ are invertible matrices and $A\geq B$. Also, $B^{-1}\geq 0$. Then, as is the case for real numbers, will $A^{-1} \leq B^{-1}$ be true?

$A\geq B$ for matrices means $A-B\geq 0$, that is, all the elements of $A- B$ are non negative.

Comment: Having worked a lot with elementwise nonnegative matrices. I doubt. Unfortunately don't have the time to build a counter example now

Comment: It's not even true for real numbers, e.g. $A=1$, $B=-1$. So the $1 \times 1$ matrices $(1)$, $(-1)$ are counterexamples.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Here $A$ and $B$ are assumed to have nonnegative entries.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @MartinR: I suspected that there was a missing hypothesis of that sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let
$$
A= \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 3&1\\1&1\end {array}
 \right], \quad B= \left[\begin {array}{cc} 2&0\\0&1\end {array}
 \right].
$$
Clearly $A-B\ge 0$ element-wise, but
$$
A^{-1}=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} {\frac{1}{2}}&-{\frac{1}{2}}
\\ -{\frac{1}{2}}&{\frac{3}{2}}\end {array} \right], \quad B^{-1}=
\left[ \begin {array}{cc} \frac12&0\\ 0&1\end {array}
 \right] 
$$
so
$$
B^{-1}-A^{-1}=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} 0&\frac{1}{2}
\\ \frac{1}{2}&-{\frac{1}{2}}\end {array} \right]
$$
which is not positive.

Comment: I have edited the question. Kindly reconsider.

Comment: Still not true; I edited the solution.

Comment: Stas Volkov, Thank you!